# Unc path with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I've a project for my PowerShell class. I'm supposed to create a copy of users folder data of client computer to the server through the network.

My script is:

```
Computer= (Get-ADComputer -Filter 'name -notlike "serveur*"').Name

$Path= "\\$pc\c$\Users"
$Destination= "E:\Sauvegardes\$pc"

Foreach($pc in $Computer) {
    robocopy $Path $Destination /MT:128
    }
```

After running the script I've found that PowerShell send me a log saying that it can't find the path `\\@{Name-PT-IT}\`

[image]
[see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10OGO.png).

To be very precise, in the image you could see the logs saying `\\@{Name-PT-IT}\` .It is because one of the name return inside `@pc` is `PT-IT`

Did I make a mistake?

Comment: Move the `$Path= "\\$pc\c$\Users"` and the `$Destination= "E:\Sauvegardes\$pc"` to the line just above the `robocopy $Path $Destination /MT:128` which is within the `foreach()` loop and see if that does it for you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked well for me. Have a nice day!